# My form doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I've made a form but it doesn't work properly. 
The form is located inside a modal window, maybe that's the issue?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LFDkE/)

And how do I make the button send the information to my e-mailadress?
I hope someone can help me out.

**the HTML**

```
<div class="modal-inner">

            <form class="cbp-mc-form">
<div class="cbp-mc-column">
    <label for="first_name">Voornaam</label>
    <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Jan">
    <label for="last_name">Achternaam</label>
    <input type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" placeholder="van Dijk">
    <label for="email">E-mailadres</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="jandemeubelman@gmail.com">
    <label for="bio">Vraag</label>
    <textarea id="bio" name="bio"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="cbp-mc-submit-wrap"><input class="cbp-mc-submit" type="submit" value="Verzenden" /></div>
<br><br></form></div>
```

**the CSS**

```
.cbp-mc-form {
position: relative;
}

.cbp-mc-form:before, 
.cbp-mc-form:after { 
content: " "; display: table; 
}

.cbp-mc-form:after { 
clear: both; 
}

.cbp-mc-column {
width: 90%;
padding: 10px 30px;
float: left;
}

.cbp-mc-form label {
display: block;
padding: 40px 5px 5px 2px;
font-size: 1.1em;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.cbp-mc-form input,
.cbp-mc-form textarea,
.cbp-mc-form select {
font-family: 'Lato', Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
line-height: 1;
font-size: 1.4em;
padding: 5px 5px;
color: #fff;
display: block;
width: 100%;
background: transparent;
}

.cbp-mc-form input,
.cbp-mc-form textarea {
border: 3px solid #fff;
width: 100%;
}

.cbp-mc-form textarea {
min-height: 100px;
}

.cbp-mc-form input:focus,
.cbp-mc-form textarea:focus,
.cbp-mc-form label:active + input,
.cbp-mc-form label:active + textarea {
outline: none;
border: 3px solid #10689a;
}

.cbp-mc-form select:focus {
outline: none;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
color: #10689a;
font-style: italic;
}

:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
color: #10689a;
font-style: italic;
}

::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
color: #10689a;
font-style: italic;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
color: #10689a;
font-style: italic;
}

.cbp-mc-submit-wrap {
text-align: center;
padding-top: 20px;
clear: both;
}

.cbp-mc-form input.cbp-mc-submit {
background: #10689a;
border: none;
color: #fff;
width: auto;
cursor: pointer;
text-transform: uppercase;
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px 15px;
font-size: 1.1em;
border-radius: 2px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.cbp-mc-form input.cbp-mc-submit:hover {
background: #1478b1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 70em) {
.cbp-mc-column {
    width: 50%;
}
.cbp-mc-column:nth-child(3) {
    width: 100%;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 48em) {
.cbp-mc-column {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
}
```

And how do I make the button send the information to my e-mailadress?
I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LFDkE/ here's the correct fiddle

Comment: add an `action=""` attribute to the form tag

Comment: You cannot send email that way, you need to use backend code to send email. Or you can use email service provider like http://sendgrid.com/

Comment: what / where is your form handler? a server http method?

Comment: To make the form send e-mail messages you will need a server-side code to fulfill the request (ASP.NET / PHP depending on your hosting), you can't do this on client-side only.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a server side sollution to accept your request. Depending on your choice the "mail sending" code can be written.

Simple example for the HTML form submit

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is also a simple example using PHP for your server side sollution:
http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

Answer (score 0):

You need back end or server side code that can have all application logic of to send email to all.
So create one back end code for to send email and then add form tag and inside it use action property as well as method i.e. get or post.

like :

```
<form action="backend file name" method="get or post">
  //your all code and controls
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

if you are using then use servlet code using class for to send mails.

if you are using .NET then use c# or other supported code.

and like so for others.

Answer (score 0):

Check - http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/email-form-mailto.html

Also you got white text on white background during filling input fields.